# Mutually Exclusive Group with Subgroup - argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to make a required mutually exclusive group where one of the options is a another group. In that subgroup each item should be required. I tried something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
exclusive = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

group = exclusive.add_argument_group()
group.add_argument("--foo", required=True)
group.add_argument("--bar", required=True)

exclusive.add_argument("--fizz")

parser.parse_args()
```

But this gives me output:

```
usage: test.py [-h] --foo FOO --bar BAR --fizz FIZZ
```

I'm expecting output like this:

```
usage: test.py [-h] ((--foo FOO --bar BAR) | --fizz FIZZ)
```

Comment: `argument_group` is a `help` tool, not a parsing one.  It will not provide you with an sort of `and/any` grouping within the `mutually_exclusive` group.

Comment: @hpaulj ah that is unfortunate, but makes sense. Any idea to achieve what I'm trying? I resorted to just checking it after calling `parse_args` and adding a note in the description, but that feels less clean than it could be.

Comment: No one will give you extra brownie points for doing everything in `argparse`.  `subparsers` and `mutually-exclusive` are the only builtin mechanisms for controlling the interactions between arguments.  You can do fancy stuff with custom `Action` classes, but post-parsing checking is usually simpler.  Remember, optionals like yours can occur in any order (and even repeatedly).  I explored extending the `xor` logic, and decided that the required user interface (including help display) was just too complex.